# Cutting string first word mvc

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

For Example, I have a string:

```
string s = "Alex Amonov,Semen Polov,John S,Alex Solid";
```

I need to show:  if first name is the same, the second name cut all elements,except first.

```
Alex A , Semen , John , Alex S
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What if there is an Alex Smith and an Alex Solid?

Comment: In your expected result, why is Alex Solid transformed to Alex S and not simply Alex?

Comment: `How can I do this?` although it seems like an question, it is not. It is simply "write it for me?". What have you tried? what did go wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To achieve the output based on the rule you defined, you can use this:

```
var s = "Alex Amonov,Semen Polov,John S,Alex Solid";

var result = "";
foreach (var name in Regex.Split(s, ",").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))
{
    var index = name.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    result += name[0] == name[index + 1] 
        ? name.Substring(0, index) + " " + name[0] + ", " 
        : name.Substring(0, index) + ", ";
}
```

But note, it would result

> Alex A, Semen, John, Alex

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way to think about an algorithm to generate that output:

1. Split the array on (`,`) to generate a list of names
2. Split each name into first-last pairs around the space
3. Group the names into matching first name groups
4. For each group having one name (no duplicate first name), output just first name
5. For each group having multiple matching first names, output first name plus last initial

This process can be done using LINQ to do the splitting and grouping, and then a loop with a temporary array to store the final results in the original order, something like this:

```
string s = "Alex Amonov,Semen Polov,John S,Alex Solid";

// split original list into separate names
var names = s.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// split names into first-last pairs, and group by matching first names groups,
// preserving information about original order/index
var nameGroups = names.Select((n, i) => Tuple.Create(i, n.Split(' '))).GroupBy(n => n.Item2[0]).ToList();

// prepare output array to store final names in original order
var result = new string[names.Length];

foreach (var nameGroup in nameGroups)
{
    // if only one matching first name in group, output just the first name
    if (nameGroup.Count() == 1)
    {
        result[nameGroup.Single().Item1] = nameGroup.Single().Item2[0];
    }
    else
    {
        // if multiple matching names, include first letter of last name
        foreach (var entry in nameGroup)
        {
            result[entry.Item1] = entry.Item2[0] + " " + entry.Item2[1][0];
        }
    }
}

// generate output comma-separated list of final output names in original order
var output = string.Join(" , ", result);
Console.WriteLine(output);      // Alex A , Semen , John , Alex S
```

There is obviously a shortcoming with this solution as pointed out by @Kaz in the comments.  If two names have the same last name initial, they will still be duplicates in the output.  In that case I suppose it could be modified to output the full last name.